# How to add many IBOutlets to an array

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsarray, iboutlet

This particular topic has always made me wonder is there a more efficient way to do it...

If I have for example 24 IBOutlets in my view controller and I want to add them to an array in viewDidLoad for easy referencing at at later point in a loop is there a better way to add to the array apart from:

```
[myArray addObject: iboutlet0];
[myArray addObject: iboutlet1];
[myArray addObject: iboutlet2];
[myArray addObject: iboutlet3];
[myArray addObject: iboutlet4];

...
...
...
```

is there a way to add the IBOutlets to the myArray in a loop block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add them in Interface Builder to an `IBOutletCollection`. Don't know how or if it is sorted so if that is important, you could set the tag value of each outlet and sort by that.

Comment: Thanks, not sure that will save anything tho as I would still need to manually add the items to the array in the first instance?